# Can I change the cable for AC laptop adapter?

Tags: laptop, power, cable, adapter

I have lost a connector for my laptop power adapter cable.

The original cable:

[image]

[image]

The original cable has `7A` `125V` on the wall side and on the charger side.

Now I have my old cable from previous laptop. It is more suited for my country(Ukraine). I plan to plug it in my power adapter as a replacement.

[image]

[image]

The replacement cable has `10A` `250V` on the wall side. And `2.5A` `250V` on the adapter side.

My adapter has `100-240V` `2A` input and `19V` `6.32A` output.

Can I replace the original cable for my adapter safely?

**EDIT**

Here is pictures for my replacement cable:

Side one tells us `2.5A`

[image]

Side two tells us `10A`

[image]

***RESULT OF A SUCH REPLACEMENT***

***I burned the replacement cable in first few seconds after I have plugged it in.***

To those who have no time to read all the posts carefully, I state a final point - ***If your replacement cable has different specs(especialy if it has lower values), then you risk a lot by plugging it in the network. Ignore those who say that `A`mpers mean nothing in this situation. Ignore all poor advices that one size fits all. The manufacturers had placed the specs not as a simple act. The detail, and in turn the device, expects some conditions to be met.***

Comment: When you make a statement like "The replacement cable has 10A 250V on the wall side"  it's complete nonsense.  And it's dangerous for anybody to say yes or no when you write something that makes no sense

Comment: No cable is going to have a spec for one side and a spec for the other side.. Can you take photos of where it says these specs?

Comment: @barlop Please see updated pictures. The cable has two ends. One end, that goes into wall is `10A` `250V`. Other side, that goes into the adapter is `2.5A` `250V`. Hope that explains things

Comment: @Яр  Not seen that before but most people would just see a power cord as a power cord.. If there is any electronics store or computer store in the ukraine you could ask to check

Comment: A power cord may have different OMs in it. Most people were attending a school. At least here in Ukraine. And there are much more to it.

Comment: @barlop: The specs are probably for the plugs, not for the cable. It's not unlikely that these are manufactured separately and rated separately from the cable...

Comment: grawity is right.  The power cord has a maximum voltage and current it can safely be used for, and it's possible that it was assembled using pre-molded plugs.  The plugs and wire might be used for any purpose.  The wall plug could be adequate for use on a heavy-duty extension cord and the adapter plug could be designed for what would typically be lower power appliances.  The power adapter manufacturer likely buys generic power cords to bundle with their product.  As long as the lowest of the voltage and current limits of the cord components are at least what the adapter requires, it's fine.

Comment: @fixer1234 "As long as the lowest of the voltage and current limits of the cord components are at least what the adapter requires, it's fine." <--  Are they? Or does he need to provide more pics showing other details?   I guess you're suggesting that the adaptor has to be <= 7A  and <= 125V which it would be, so he's fine?  Pretty much specs on plugs of a power cord will always be fine for a laptop then.

Comment: @barlop, no more pix needed.  It's clear what the OP is seeing.  The adapter has AC input of 100-240V 2A.  The lowest-rated component of the cord is the adapter side plug rated 2.5A 250V.  So it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Appliance manufacturers often find it cost effective to buy power cords and cables from companies set up to manufacture those parts.  The company manufacturing power cords will have molds for the different kinds of plugs, and mixes and matches those components for cords for different purposes.  They might use the same wall plug mold and components to make a variety of power cords.  So the wall plug will be designed to handle up to fairly high requirements.  The plug for the adapter side might typically be used with relatively low-power appliances, so it is designed to meet those needs.

The information molded onto each plug reflects the limit of what the plug is designed to safely handle.  The wire in between likely has still another rating, and the choice of wire depends on things like the cord length and the environmental conditions it needs to handle.  The finished cord can be used for any application that doesn't exceed the limits of the "weakest link", i.e., the lowest-rated component used in that cord.

In your case, the power adapter takes AC input of 100-240V 2A.  The range of voltage means that it can be used in pretty much any country because that covers the range of nominal voltage standards.  It also means that the power cord will require the right type of plug for the country where it will be used.  The power adapter manufacturer can provide the same unit for use anywhere by just bundling it with the correct power cord.

So the unit is already designed to take interchangeable cords provided the cord has the correct plugs and can safely handle the adapter's power requirements (which are pretty low in the scheme of appliances with detachable power cords).

The lowest-capacity component of your replacement cord is the plug for the adapter, which is rated for 2.5A 250V.  That exceeds what the adapter needs, so the cord is fine to use.

The last sentence in the question states that you burned the replacement cable within the first few seconds of plugging it in.  It isn't clear what you're referring to there, but any kind of "burning" should be unrelated to the ratings on the cable or your use of it.  If you're saying that using the cable caused melting, burning, arcing, or something of that nature, that sounds like a defect or previous damage.

There also should not be an issue of the plug contacts having different usage assignments (like which contact is ground), where a European cord makes different connections from a US cord.  There are international standards for how the contacts are used (to avoid differences in contact usage causing burning or a shock hazard).

Comment: The adapter actually has 2.0A on input side. Still I burned my cable. Can’t upvote your post. Have less than fifteen reputation.

Comment: I have bought a new connector. See where it gets me.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your question, you have a cable that fits your wall socket, and you lost the adapter for the original one.

The important side of the cable is the one that fits the AC adapter (charger). The other side (AC wall socket) is not much important, because a laptop has a small current requirement (let's say about 0,8 Ampere at 240V, or 1,4 Ampere at 110V).
So if the new cable fits the socket in the adapter side, you can safely use it.

If the socket in the adapter is not the same of the cable (bigger or smaller or with a different number of pins), you cannot use it.

Comment: You write "If the socket in the adapter is not the same of the cable (bigger or smaller or with a different number of pins), you cannot use it." <--- adaptors are very cheap can be less than $10

Comment: I have harshly written my previous comment, after I saw the first comment in the list. The commenter disoriented me and I marked the answer as wrong. Now I see that your answer has a point. But i have burned my cable before I did see your answer.

Comment: You should edit your post to put emphasis on that that the cable should meet the ac adapter requirements. Fit is misleading word here.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко You burnt your cable?!

Comment: You write "you loose the adapter for the original one."   <-- That is not English. What does that mean?

Comment: I have lost my wall connector. I’m not a English person.

Comment: @barlop I ***burned*** my cable. Exacly that. The side that is close to a awall socket had melted in about 3 seconds. Not completely melted, but the plastic cover did start to drip.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко you could try electronics.stackexchange.com  if you want to be more sure. Personally I haven't really looked at the labelling on such things, and these leads with plugs on are called kettle leads and i've found them to be pretty much the same just gotta make sure they're the right connector. I'm in the UK.  But if you want to be sure then you can check on electronics.stackexchange.com as your question is very much an electronics one